# Which URLs/paths are available for testing as local variables in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm going through the Rails Tutorial online book and just finished session 3.4.4 "Setting the root route":

After updating my config/routes.rb file to

```
root 'static_pages#home'
```

The bin/rails test command fails:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `static_pages_home_url' for #<StaticPagesControllerTest:0x007f89d4f73860>
test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
```

So "static_pages_home_url" existed when config/routes.rb had:

```
get 'static_pages/home'
```

But it doesn't exist anymore.

How do I check out which which urls are available as local variables for testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rails routes` and check the `Prefix` column.